# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2.errors'

Tags: python, import, psycopg2

I have `psycopg2` module installed, but I can't import exceptions from this library:

```
$ pip freeze | grep psycopg
psycopg2==2.7.7
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Nov  5 2019, 17:21:00)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> from psycopg2.errors import InsufficientPrivilege, UndefinedTable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2.errors'
```

Comment: `psycopg2.errors` was introduced in version 2.8.

Comment: Yes, it was... Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @john-gordon [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218002/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-psycopg2-errors#comment104651809_59218002).

> psycopg2.errors was introduced in version 2.8.